# How do I know whether to reboot after upgrading packages in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I have a PC running Ubuntu server.

Sometimes when I ssh into it, I get a message that some packages need upgrading.

I upgrade the software by running (as root)

```
aptitude update && aptitude safe-upgrade
```

Sometimes that is enough. But sometimes I need to reboot as well, and I am not told this until I ssh in subsequently.  How can I find out sooner?

Ideally I'd like to upgrade by running something like

```
aptitude update && aptitude safe-upgrade &&
if aptitude needs-reboot ; then shutdown -r now ; fi
```

but the `aptitude needs-reboot` command does not exist. What should I run instead?

---

Clarifications:

- Actually I have two PCs, one running 10.04 (lucid) and the other running 11.04 (natty). I'd hope it would be the same solution for both.
- Strictly command line solutions only please. One of these PCs doesn't have a display, and neither of them has a keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

One sub-par way---maybe specific to Ubuntu---is to check the existence of this file:

```
/var/run/reboot-required
```

If it exists, a reboot is required.

So a Bash function in `.bash_rc` (and co.) could do the job:

```
function needs_reboot {
  if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
    read -p "Restart needed. Reboot? (y/N) " answer;
    if [ "$answer" = "y" -o "$answer" = "Y" ]; then
      reboot;
    fi
  else
    echo "No restart";
  fi
}
```

Where does this idea come from? MOTD gets updated at login time by the `pam_motd` process, reading its contents from the `/etc/update-motd.d` directory. In this directory, there is a `/etc/update-motd.d/98-reboot-required` script (on Ubuntu 12_04) that checks for the existence of our `/var/run/reboot-required`. That's apparently how a reboot advice is decided. So the function above just makes the same check, interactively.

I'd really like to get that directly from APT, but for now, this works...

Answer (score 1):

How about this (run as root):
`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade --dry-run | grep linux-; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then yes | apt-get dist-upgrade && reboot; else yes | apt-get dist-upgrade; fi`

If there is a kernel update `grep linux-` will return 0 and then you will reboot. The `yes` command could be replaced by `apt-get dist-upgrade --assume-yes`. There will be no reboot if no kernel update is found.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reboot if the kernel is upgraded.

Comment: Is there an easy way of scripting that, without resorting to parsing the output of `aptitude safe-upgrade`?